# Magento 2.3.3 - Programmatically shipment email sent in the wrong language

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipment, email-translation, i18n

I am trying to programmatically create the shipment and I succeeded in this operation.
To do this I create a new CLI Command which I obviously run by command line.

I have only 1 storeview and the default locale is Italian.

The problem is about sending the email to the customer because it is always sent in English.

I try different ways to send the shipment email and the last is using the class

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender
```

in this way

```
$this->shipmentSender->send($shipment);
```

after had set

```
$this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);
```

I also tried the class

```
Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier
```

in this way

```
$this->shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);
```

I also try to embed the code inside a statement of EnvironmentEmulation using

```
Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
```

using the following code

```
$this->emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($order->getStoreId());

// send shipping confirmation e-mail to customer
$this->shipmentNotifier->notify($shipment);

$this->emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
```

I don't know if this is a bug, as many others I found or if I'm wrong.

**Note:** if I create and send the shipment from the backend the email is in the correct language.

**EDIT:**

I try executing the code by external php script using ObjectManager with the following code:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$orderId = "000000009";

$order = $obj->get('Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);

$notifier = $obj->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\NotifierInterface');

foreach($order->getShipmentsCollection() as $ship) {

    $notifier->notify($order,$ship);

}

?>
```

...but I get the same result: the shipment email is sent in English and not Italian.

Please, help me!

Thank you.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you been able to fix it in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug in Magento prior to version 2.3.3-p1 and has been fixed since:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23333

Apparently in this commit PR :https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/23338

Even though the PR was merged in June 2019, Magento 2.3.3-p1 was only released in January 2020.